# Typescript typeguard on the first generic element of a type

Tags: typescript, generics, types, keyof, typeguards

I have an `Actions` type that need to be mapped to a set of callbacks in the `actionMap` variable.

However, I'm unsure on how to enforce type of the first generic element of the `Action` type. Clearly `key in keyof Actions` isn't doing the trick here. What would I need to use instead?

```
export interface Action<T, U> {
  type: T,
  data: U,
}

export type Actions =
  | Action<"something", {}>
  | Action<"somethingElse", {}>

const actionMap: { [key in keyof Actions]: (action: Actions) => any } = {
  // I'd like the value of the `type` property of all my actions enforced here. Ex:
  // "something": (action) => {}
  // "somethingElse": (action) => {}
}
```

If I’m asking the wrong question, what is a better question? I'm not sure I'm using the jargon accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using indexed access types to grab a property of the interface, and `Extract` to narrow down the type of `action` in the function.

```
export interface Action<T, U> {
  type: T,
  data: U,
}

export type Actions =
  | Action<"something", { something: true}>
  | Action<"somethingElse", { somethingElse: true }>

const actionMap: { [K in Actions['type']]: (action: Extract<Actions, { type: K }>) => any } = {
  "something": (action) => {}, // TS knows action.data.something exists
  "somethingElse": (action) => {} // TS knows action.data.somethingElse exists
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! I'll make sure to read more on that :)